# Creating GUI menu depending on user selection in another GUI in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, popup, matlab-guide, popupmenu

I am trying to develop a GUI involving two popup menus. In the first popup menu, there are 3 options. The number of options in the second popup menu should depend on the selected option in the first menu.

If the first option is selected in the first popup menu, there should be 4 options in the second popup menu. Similarly, if the second option is selected in the first popup menu, there should be 5 options in the second popup menu and so on.

Most importantly I have to provide separate formulae for each option from second popup menu.

How can I do this?

Comment: We won't create it for you, but if you show us what you have tried so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried `doc uicontrol`?